# Cart Throb / Subscriptions Gateway issues

Tags: cartthrob, shopping-cart, subscriptions

I have an existing working live store running CartThrob using Moneris as the payment gateway.

I want to add subscriptions (auto renewal) but CartThrob has not developed a payment gateway to work with subscriptions even though Moneris seems to offer vault/token requirements.

I was hoping to maybe use Stripe as an option JUST for subscriptions but I need to use Moneris for all other purchases.  I though maybe I could use a gateway selector and get people to choose Stripe is they are purchasing a subscription but then I found out the Stripe does not like the gateway switcher and will through you errors based on the JS they use.

Does anyone have any ideas?  I have have ZERO luck getting any feedback or support directly from Cart Throb. Tries to get a quote for developing a new Moneris plugin that would work with  subscriptions.  They didn't even reply.